# Graduating Canadian F-1 Student: TN vs. OPT

Tags: usa, canadian-citizens, employment

I am a Canadian student graduating from a US university. As far as I know, I have two visa options when it comes employment in the industry: F-1 OPT and TN.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? For one thing, I know that OPT allows me to work for multiple employers for an unrestricted amount of time each day for a year (before extension), but TN restricts me to one employer only. I need to pay a ~$400 USCIS processing fee however, for OPT. Are there other considerations in choosing between the two?

Comment: @Dorothy, please do add comments when closing. It gets flagged for us if closed without a comment.

Comment: @ouflak please do add comments when closing. It gets flagged for us if closed without a comment.

Comment: @Gayot-fow please do add comments when closing. It gets flagged for us if closed without a comment.

Comment: @Dipen-Shah please do add comments when closing. It gets flagged for us if closed without a comment.

Comment: @Greg-Hewgill please do add comments when closing. It gets flagged for us if closed without a comment.